# Распознание объектов, ошибка при запуске

Tags: python, tensorflow

Я использовал mask_rcnn_coco.h5 в качестве предварительно обученной модели.
И я получаю такую ошибку при запуске.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Damir\IdeaProjects\namber\tenzer.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Damir\IdeaProjects\namber\tenzer.py", line 10, in main
    obg()
  File "C:\Users\Damir\IdeaProjects\namber\tenzer.py", line 5, in obg
    segment.load_model(r'C:\Users\Damir\IdeaProjects\namber\mask_rcnn_balloon.h5')
  File "C:\Users\Damir\IdeaProjects\nero\venv\lib\site-packages\pixellib\instance\__init__.py", line 65, in load_model
    self.model.load_weights(model_path, by_name= True)
  File "C:\Users\Damir\IdeaProjects\nero\venv\lib\site-packages\pixellib\instance\mask_rcnn.py", line 2110, in load_weights
    hdf5_format.load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name(f, layers)
  File "C:\Users\Damir\IdeaProjects\nero\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 790, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group_by_name
    raise ValueError('Layer #' + str(k) +' (named "' + layer.name +
ValueError: Layer #389 (named "mrcnn_bbox_fc"), weight <tf.Variable 'mrcnn_bbox_fc/kernel:0' shape=(1024, 324) dtype=float32> has shape (1024, 324), but the saved weight has shape (1024, 8).

Process finished with exit code 1
```

код:

```
from  pixellib.instance import instance_segmentation

def obg():
    segment = instance_segmentation()
    segment.load_model(r'C:\Users\Damir\IdeaProjects\namber\mask_rcnn_balloon.h5')
    segment.segmentImage(image_path='images.jfif',output_image_name='12345.jpg',show_bboxes=True)


def main ():
    obg()
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Гугл транслейт может помочь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я конечно не уверен, но может из за этого: has shape (1024, 324), but the saved weight has shape (1024, 8)